# How to fix error

Tags: error, script

> How to fix error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'
>
> var script = document.createElement("script"); 
>   script.type="text/javascript"; script.src = 'url';
>   script.innerHTML="dataLayer = [ ] ";
>   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: how to add this script in head tag ,<script>dataLayer=[{"transactionId":"100087965","transactionTotal":1090,"transactionTax":0,"transactionShipping":0,"currencyCode":"LKR","transactionProducts":[{"sku":"ZZ48-XL","name":"White Cold Shoulder Floral Top","category":"Default Category Clothing Tops ","price":1090,"quantity":1}]}];<script>console.log('Debug Objects: </script>

Comment: Please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737442/document-writescript-throws-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is in `script.innerHTML="dataLayer = [ ] ";` line. Actually, you are trying to concatenate string double quote `""` but inside the `[]` array, there is also double quote`""` available. So you need to change `script.innerHTML= 'dataLayer = [ ]';`

I have changed it and it's working now.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type="text/javascript";
script.innerHTML='dataLayer=[{"transactionId":"100087965","transactionTotal":1090,"transactionTax":0,"transactionShipping":0,"currencyCode":"LKR","transactionProducts":[{"sku":"ZZ48-XL","name":"White Cold Shoulder Floral Top","category":"Default Category Clothing Tops ","price":1090,"quantity":1}]}];console.log("Debug Objects:");';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```